# Get Future List in a new root

Tags: flutter, async-await, future

Maybe my problem is easy, but i'm look for it from more than one week...

I have a Json file, and in a function file i get a list from this Json. So in this step, i get a Future

But Now i want to transfert this List to a new Root with MaterialPageRoute and i don't understand how i can do it.

```
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => JourAffiche (
      jouree : givefuturelist(context, detail_jour[1])
    )
    ),
  );

liste_du_jour(jour) async {
  List listt = await afficher_menu(jour);
  return listt;
}

 givefuturelist(context, jour) {
   return FutureBuilder<List>(
      future: liste_du_jour(jour),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return snapshot.data;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
  );
}
```

That i would like it's to get the List in the UI

```
class JourAffiche extends StatefulWidget {
  JourAffiche({@required this.jouree});
   Future<List> jouree;

  @override
  _JourAfficheState createState() => _JourAfficheState();
}

class _JourAfficheState extends State<JourAffiche> {
  String _value = null;
  List<String> _values = [];

@override
  void initState() {
    _values = widget.jouree;
    _value = _values.elementAt(0);
  }
```

But it's not working...
Somebody can help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1

```
final List data = await getData();

Navigator.push(
  context,
  new MaterialPageRoute<void>(
    builder: (_) => JourAffiche(jouree: data),
  ),
);

class JourAffiche extends StatefulWidget {
  const JourAffiche({Key key, this.jouree}) : super(key: key);
  final List jouree;

  @override
  _JourAfficheState createState() => _JourAfficheState();
}

....
```

2

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  new MaterialPageRoute<void>(
    builder: (_) => JourAffiche2(jouree: getData()),
  ),
);

class JourAffiche2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const JourAffiche({Key key, this.jouree}) : super(key: key);
  final Future<List> jouree;

  @override
  _JourAfficheState createState() => _JourAfficheState();
}

....
```

Answer (score 0):

Get data first, then navigate to route with `JourAffiche`. This is how would navigation function looks like. Call it from some action handler, e.g. button tap.

```
  Future<void> goToJourAffiche(dynamic jour) async {
    final jouree = await liste_du_jour(jour);

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => JourAffiche(jouree: jouree),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Also you can show loader while waiting the future to complete:

```
class SomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => SomeWidgetState();
}

class SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {
  var isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build function with uses [isLoading] flag to show or not to show some loader widget
    return ...;
  }

  Future<void> goToJourAffiche(dynamic jour) async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    final jouree = await liste_du_jour(jour);
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => JourAffiche(jouree: jouree),
      ),
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i can't understand how i can exactly integrate a loader to my view.
I have in one side the ui that is JourAffiche, and in other side the function file, so i don't understand... (sorry it'll sur that is simple.. but i don't understand)

Comment: Could you provide code of class or widget from where you call `Navigator.push`?

Comment: I'm not sur to understand, but i know that it's my weekness not your explanation, so i'm sorry. 
Thanks a lot for your help